# How to create a laravel project in htdocs folder

Tags: command-line, 20.04, php, laravel, php-cli

I am a web developer. I have created projects in Windows OS, but now I have completely switched to Ubuntu 20.04. I have installed PHP and `composer`. But when I want to create a Laravel project in `htdocs` it creates project but `vendor` folder is missing. When I write `composer update` in CLI in `htdocs` folder it shows these errors:

```
1=>
Cannot create cache directory /home/saad/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /home/saad/.cache/composer/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

2=>
PHP temp directory (/tmp) does not exist or is not writable to Composer. Set sys_temp_dir in your php.ini

3=>
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
```

Then shows these:

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v7.25.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.24.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework 7.x-dev requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.24 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v7.24.0, v7.25.0].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get into the project folder to run composer ...

example:

```
cd path/to/htdocs/your-laravel-project-folder
```

Then run

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

One of you problems is that `composer` don't have write permission to `/home/saad/.cache/composer/`.

Another problem is that you are missing the `php-mbstring` package. Install it by:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-mbstring
```